# How to build offline RPM deploy using existing RPMs?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I am wondering if there is anything like taking existing RPM packages and putting them into one main RPM for offline deploy/installs.

What I am trying to do is install MySQL Server on CentOS 6.5. I would like to distribute this to our servers which do ***not*** have access to repos outside of company network. These packages will be uploaded to our internal repo either seperately or in one package (hopefully).

So instead of running `yum install mysql-community*.rpm` I am hoping that I can somehow package the below RPMs into one and on target servers just run `yum install some_standard_package.rpm`.

- `mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`
- `mysql-community-common-5.7.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`
- `mysql-community-libs-5.7.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`
- `mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`
- `mysql-community-server-5.7.17-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`

I have searched for a solution but all I find are pages instructing me how to rebuild an RPM package form source which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You can build your own rpm that installs the rpms.

Answer (score 2):

afaik there is no way to bring multiple rpms into one rpm. You can however:

- get all the original rpms (consider using `zypper --download-only`)
- put them in a folder
- (optionally) compress the folder
- transfer that folder to you other servers
- (optionally) extract the folder
- cd folder
- `rpm -Uvh *.rpm` (that is: install all rpms you find in this folder)

Answer (score 2):

You can download the RPMs to a local repo, build a group file for them in the local repo and then install the group with yum:

```
 yum-groups-manager -n "My Group" --id=mygroup --save=mygroups.xml --mandatory mysql-community-client mysql-community-common ....

 createrepo -g mygroups.xml /svr/repo
```

and install with

```
 yum group install "My Group"
```

I have not tested this: it's cribbed from [here](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumGroups).

Comment: You can simply `rsync` the rpms to a given directory and then use `createrepo` which creates the rpm metadata within that directory allowing it to be used as a yum/zypper/rpm repository for any distro using rpm as the package manager. (your thinking is correct)

Answer (score 0):

`offline_yum_install` installs rpm packages with dependencies off line using `yum`. Its output is a `mysql.tgz` which has an install_script and all packages that the rpm depends on.

Have a look at [the offline_yum_install github repo](https://github.com/ylyxf/offline_yum_install).

Answer (score 0):

`yumdownloader` could be an option, example in this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66927190/5078874