# How to install a rpm package and its dependencies offline

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, rpm

I want to install a rpm package, (e.g. python 3), and all of its dependencies in a linux server that does not have internet connection.

How can I do that?

Comment: [How to use yum to get all RPMs required, for offline use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259640/56041) and friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CentOS/RedHat you can use `yumdownloader` for specific packages, this downloads all RPMs required, then, compress the directory, upload it to the server without Internet access and install RPMs.

[Here](https://adrianescutia.github.io/adrianes/snippets/kubernetes/install-kubernetes-docker-offline#download-docker-online-machinedocker-host) you can find and example, installing Kubernetes without Internet access.

```sh
yumdownloader --assumeyes --destdir=/var/rpm_dir/docker-ce --resolve docker-ce
tar -czvf d4r-k8s.tar.gz /var/rpm_dir
# Upload files
scp d4r-k8s.tar.gz root@YOUR-IP:/root
# Connect to your server
ssh root@YOUR-IP
tar -xzvf /root/d4r-k8s.tar.gz -C /
# install Docker:
yum install -y --cacheonly --disablerepo=* /var/rpm_dir/docker-ce/*.rpm
```

Comment: FYI if you get "yumdownloader: command not found" you can install it with: `yum install yum-utils`

Comment: This does not work for in me CentOS 7 even with the specified docker-ce package. It does not download any dependent images but only the docker-ce package. However, this answer did work for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260261/221435

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you already downloaded the package before from another machine that has internet access and FTP the files to your server, you can use the following command to install a rpm

```
rpm -ivh package_name_x85_64.rpm
```

options:

- i = This installs a new package.
- v = Print verbose information
- h = Print 50 hash marks as the package archive is unpacked.

You can also check the rpm manual for more options and details

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, but it is quite tricky and might mess up your servers, so be **very careful**.

Nomenclature:

- **online** : your system that is connected to the repositories
- **offline**: your system that is not connected

Steps:

Compress your rpm database from the **offline** system and transfer it to the **online** system:

```
cd /var/lib/rpm/
tar -cvzf /tmp/rpmdb.tgz *
scp /tmp/rpmdb.tgz root@online:/tmp
```

on your **online** system; replace your rpm db with the one from the **offline** system:

```
cp -r /var/lib/rpm{,.bak} # back up your rpmdb from your online system. Make sure not to lose this!!
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/*
cd /var/lib/rpm
tar -xvf /tmp/rpmdb.tgz # now your online system pretends to have the rpm database from the offline system. Don't start really installing / uninstalling rpms or you'll break everything
```

now simulate your update with download-only (I didn't run this with yum but with zypper, but it should be similar):

```
zypper up --download-only
```

Now you can fetch all the downloaded packages and they should suffice for updating your offline system

And now restore your **online** machine:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm
cp -r /var/lib/rpm{.bak,}
```

Comment: unfortunately zypper will not download ALL dependencies, so there will be missed dependencies in case of applying such installation on the system with too different environment