# CentOS 7 - Install MonoDevelop and Python 3.0 by using the RPM tool (Do not use yum)

Tags: python-3.x, centos7, rpm

I have been assigned a project to install Mono and Python 3.0 on CentOS 7 minimal (terminal version). I cannot download the packages using gui or yum and I must use the RPM tool to install.

I downloaded the rpm using the 'wget' tool but when tried to install using 'rpm -ivh monodevelop.blah.blah.blah.rpm' It said I needed to install a big list of dependencies. What is the best way to install these dependencies without using yum? and where can I find them?

This is the rpm I was trying to install.
http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos7-stable/m/monodevelop/monodevelop-7.5.0.1254-0.xamarin.1.epel7.x86_64.rpm

I am a beginner in Linux and I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really cannot use yum, then the only solution I see is downloading all dependencies; putting all in /some/directory, then:

```
rpm -ivh /some/directory/*.rpm
```

You can look at another answer of mine for how to download all the dependencies, but take care because that is rather advanced stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683836/2082964 .

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess I'm just having a really hard time even finding these dependencies to download.

Comment: don't you have another centos where you can simulate the installation with yum; which will give you the exact list of your requirements...