# Download all dependencies recursively from a rpm file

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I know that I can retrieve all dependencies recursively using `yumdownloader  --downloadonly`. But is there a way that I can do it by passing the an rpm file instead of the package name? like `yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm --downloadonly --downloaddir=xx` with some option to download dependencies of chrome's dependencies.

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683836/2082964

Comment: @Chris Maes no I wouldn't do that. I don't have the root privileges and I want to be able to install the package using only one server.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you pull the NEVRA from the RPM file and pass it to yumdownloader

`yumdownloader --resolve $(rpm -qp ./<RPMPACKAGE>.rpm --queryformat="%{nevra}")`

Comment: when I tried this command `yumdownloader --resolve $(rpm -qp google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm --queryformat="%{nevra}") --downloadonly --downloaddir=myDir`
I got this message `No Match for argument google-chrome-stable-78.0.3904.70-1.x86_64
Nothing to download`

Comment: Do you havew a repo set up in which it can resolve this package ?

Comment: I dont have the root privileges to do so.